# Inputs and textareas in a Team Foundation Server Web Access custom work item control: backspace doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, tfs

Let's say I've created a work item custom control and I add a `<textarea />`.

Because of some client TFS JavaScript library event handler on `keydown`, <kbd>backspace</kbd> key won't remove characters (or selected characters). It does just do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating a workaround, I figured out that, since TFS adds some event handler which modifies default text input behavior, I had to bind an event handler to the whole `<textarea />` in order to stop event bubbling.

But when I tried to call jQuery's `event.stopPropagation()`, instead of stopping the whole event bubbling, <kbd>backspace</kbd> started to trigger the Web browser's back button.

For now, I've found this solution:

```
$("textarea").on("keydown", function(e) {
                                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                                e.returnValue = false;
                            });
```

This solved the problem!